# Update Badge Count in Background InActive State iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, background, push, hybrid

I'm working on Ionic v2 (Hybrid) application with Push notification enabled, App receives notification in every state (foreground/background/active/inactive etc.) but I had a challenge with updating App Icon Badge count in Background mode, which I achieved via adding **"content-available":1** in APNS payload and its start working...but Badge count is not updating when I killed the app instance...

Can anyone help on this?

on the other hand, I do have other ideas too like keeping a track of badge count at server side and send the updated badge via payload adding **badge** property, but I don't like to go this route as I still feel there should be a straightforward solution to achieve this...

Comment: If you terminate the app then notifications aren't delivered to your app delegate. Moral of the story: don't terminate the app if you want it to receive silent push notifications.

Comment: Well, terminating is not in our hand, User could do whatever they want... what I could conclude then there is no way to update badge count if gets killed? else keeping a track of count?

Comment: If you don't track it on your server and send the badge count along with the notification, then no. You could supply a default babe count of 1 in the notification so that at least something will be shown if the app is terminated.

Comment: Then it would mislead the User, I think keeping a track is the only way to go... Anyways thanks for your comments.